# What does 'so' actually indicate?

Tags: adverbs

> 1. There's God, so here's humans. (Meaning the reason humans exist here is that God exists there)

Is it indicating 'is' here? As 'so' is classified as adverb, there seems to be no words other than 'is' that 'so' can indicate.

> 2. ‘Is he coming?’ ‘I hope so.’

Dictionaries register this usage of 'so' as indicating the whole preceding sentence, but I think it seems actually and only indicating 'coming' because of the same reason above.

Comment: Seems like a dictionary pretty much answers this question. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so Your first example is definition 3, while your second is definition 1.

Comment: @Acccumulation Well, as you see my question, I want to hear opinions, though.

Comment: @Acccumulation: while that is true, as this is a site for English *learners*, it may be helpful to write up an answer explaining why this is the case. Also, give the myriad definitions on that page you could be more clear on which definition you are referring to e.g. the first definition as the third point of the first definition "therefore" vs relating to the third entry (which is for an adjective usage)

Comment: @Acccumulation - I agree with sharur. With 20 definitions on that page, I think some additional explanation and clarification would be both warranted and helpful.

Comment: @SIS: Could you expand on the meaning or context of the first sentence. I'd like to improve my answer, but I am unsure of what the first sentence means.

Comment: @sharur Edited, but if you are still unsure, then, better to bring another example.

Comment: @SIS: Thank you, your edit was very helpful; as a native (AmEnglish) speaker, that is a strange formulation (how the idea is said, rather than the idea itself), and theological statements can become...contentious, so I try to avoid assumptions on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

1. "So" can be an adverb (modifying a verb or adjective); it can also be used as other parts of speech, including a conjunction (joining to sentence structures together), an adjective (modifying a noun or noun phrase), or a pronoun(as a placeholder for a specific noun).

In this example, "so" is a conjunction, joining together the two clauses while indicating a causal relationship between them. We could re-write the sentence without changing the meaning to use "so" as an adverb as

> "God is there, and so humanity is here/humans are here"

"So" is still indicating a causal relationship, but the actual joining of the clauses being dealt with by the conjunction "and".

Also, strictly speaking, if "humans" are used, the contraction of "is" should not be used, but some, including native speakers, might overlook this in order to create or maintain a parallelism).

"Therefore" could be used as a synonym for "so" in this sense.

2. "So" in this sentence is being used as a adverb, *indicating* the preceding sentence, but *modifying* the verb "hope", as what is hoped for is the preceding sentence to be true. It could be rewritten as:

   > "Is he coming?" "I hope that he is coming".